# send her victorious, happy and glorious -- how do you understand that grammatically? (from "God Save the Queen")

Tags: comprehension

The entire lyrics to the anthem can be found [here](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/u/uks+national+anthem/god+save+the+queen_20983467.html). But what I'm having trouble with is in the first verse:

> God save our gracious Queen
>   Long live our noble Queen
>   God save the Queen
>   **Send her victorious**
>   **Happy and glorious**
>   Long to reign over us
>   God save the Queen

I'm not sure how one should understand that part of the anthem. First of all, they're asking God to send the Queen what or where? Secondly, how do those three adjectives, *victorious*, *happy* and *glorious*, work there grammatically? I'm sorry, but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the request to God is:

> Send her to reign over us.

Now fill in *how / with what properties* to send her:

> victorious, happy and glorious

and *how* she should reign:

> long

If you scramble it a bit up to match the [music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Save_the_Queen) (and as poetry is "allowed" to do), you end up with:

> Send her victorious
>   Happy and glorious
>   Long to reign over us.

---

(Honestly: Singing "Make her victorious, happy and glorious and send her to reign over us for a long time." just wouldn't do, would it?)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I'm Australian and that was our national anthem when I was a child, and I never knew. I'd slightly wondered, but no enough to ask, as the overall meaning was clear.